# Reciveing the Error code: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am receiving an error while defining a function. Am not able to debug it. Please help.

```
def _rescale(betweenness, n, normalized, directed=False, k=None, endpoints=False):

    if normalized:
        if endpoints:
            if n < 2:
                scale = None  # no normalization
            else:
                # Scale factor should include endpoint nodes
                scale = 1 / (n * (n - 1))
        elif n <= 2:
            scale = None  # no normalization b=0 for all nodes
        else:
            scale = 1 / ((n - 1) * (n - 2))
    else:  # rescale by 2 for undirected graphs
        if not directed:
            scale = 0.5
        else:
            scale = None
    if scale is not None:
        if k is not None:
            scale = scale * n / k
        for v in betweenness:
            betweenness[v] *= scale
    return betweenness
```

The snippet of received error is:

```
      scale = scale * n / 
     for v in betweenness: 
        betweenness[v] *= scale
```

return betweenness

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: On the basis of the exception you've shown, the variable *v* must be a dictionary. Maybe *betweenness* is a list of dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you try to access an element from a tuple with the element from the tuple. I have made a small example to show you.

```py
data = ("test", "hello", "friend")
for v in data:
    print(data[v])
```

Prints the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tcastron/PycharmProjects/<project>/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(data[v])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

To fix you issue you should use the `len` function to access every part of your tuple:

```py
for v in range(len(betweenness)):
    betweenness[v] *= scale
```

But from what I understand from your question, betweennes is a tuple and you can't assign new variables to a tuple.

Hope this helps a little bit though.

Comment: in _rescale(betweenness, n, normalized, directed, k, endpoints)
      3         scale = 1 / ((n - 1) * (n - 2))
      4         for v in range(len(betweenness)):
----> 5             betweenness[v] *= scale
      6 
      7     return betweenness

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *=: 'dict' and 'float'

Comment: Give more information about your codes, the data types of the variables absolutely unclear